# Having an issue passing by reference / value

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I've got this method that is passed an array of files. It then replaces any `/` with `\\`. Then I call a method and pass the array to it, which puts the argument into a *new* array, formats the itand returns the new array. Next, I call the same method again, pass it the same local array, format it differently, and `out` both arrays. Problem is, the second method call is retaining the format from the first method call.

```
    public void Verify(string[] svnFiles, out string[] local, out string[] build)
    {            
        //replace / with double \\
        var transformed = TransformToFolders(svnFiles);

        build = GetFiles(_buildPath, transformed);
        local = GetFiles(_localPath, transformed);
    }

    private static string[] GetFiles(string path, params string[] files)
    {
        var moddedFiles = files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
            moddedFiles[i] = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", path, moddedFiles[i]);

        return moddedFiles;
    }
```

So when I call `local = GetFiles(_localPath, transformed);` `transformed` has the same values as `moddedFiles`. `GetFiles` used to manipulate its `files` parameter directly and I was getting the same behavior, so that's why I tried creating a new array, but `moddedFiles` seems to still just be a reference instead of an actual copy. Is there an easy way to make an actual copy of it so that way I'm not getting basically `_localPath\_buildPath\moddedFile`?

Comment: This is not related to your question but is a recommendation based on my personal experience. I have always got hurt in the eye when I used multiple out arguments. IMHO I consider that a bad pattern. Instead I create model classes with output values as properties and return that as the result of function.

Comment: Frankly I'm not a huge fan of it either, slowly working on refactoring this project I inherited. I will probably change it. I think it's ugly and hard to follow. Or at least, the full method is-- I had stripped it down to just the core essentials for this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var moddedFiles = (string[]) files.Clone();
```

That will create a shallow copy of the array, which is largely equivalent to a deep copy when it comes to strings, as they're immutable.

However, a cleaner (IMO) alternative would be to use LINQ:

```
private static string[] GetFiles(string path, params string[] files)
{
    return files.Select(file => string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", path, file))
                .ToArray();
}
```

Or if you really want to keep your original rough approach, you don't need to clone the array really - just create a new array of the right size.

```
private static string[] GetFiles(string path, params string[] files)
{
    var moddedFiles = new string[files.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        moddedFiles[i] = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", path, files[i]);
    }
    return moddedFiles;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. For some reason I didn't think I could cast it to a string array-- I just looking at Clone / MemberwiseClone. This worked, and I'll mark it in 10 minutes :)

Comment: @sab669: Have a look at my edit for a cleaner approach though :)